# The best way to save and restore inputs values for sorting dataTable (JSF, Richfaces)

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, datatables, restore

For a past few days I'm facing a task which became problematic for me.

I'm using `rich:dataTable` with own filtering and sorting columns. Simple inputs or selects with standard sorting and filtering beans in back end. My problem is that I need to remember somehow this sorting and filtering values for many forms to restore them in some case whens - eg.: user uses a back button (the most important case). I know how to handle browser back button, but I don't know have to save and restore my values in some easy and clear way. The important thing is that ***I can't use*** `rich:extandedDataTable` and I use view scope of beans.

(One of solutions was to use session scope bean to manage s&f, but make one bean for one form is far to expensive and making one such a bean is quite complicated to use in the way i want to use it.)

So, my question is: how can I do it? What is the best practice to deal with such a things? Which path should I go?

I'm using RF 4.3 and Mojarra 2.1.17 (it's not so important I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the `stateVar` attribute would be ideal for your needs,but documentation on it is sparse and no one seems to really know what to do with it. I'll recommend the following hack, which basically has you save and restore the state of the datatable variables by hand

If you simply want to preserve the current filter state of the table, RF datatable has a `getComponentState()` method that does basically that. If you want specific values to store, you'll have to dive into the datatable yourself. Whatever you choose, you'll have to do it sometime in the component's lifecycle

1. Define a suitable `<f:event/>` listener in which you will capture the state variables of the datatable. I recommend the `preValidate`.

   ```
    <rich:extendedDataTable binding="#{bean.table}" ...>       
      <f:event type="preValidate" listener="bean.saveTableState"/>        
    </rich:extendedDataTable>
   ```

   Then define the method in your backing bean that will retrieve the state variables from the table binding

   ```
    public void saveTableState(ComponentSystemEvent evt){
         UIExtendedDataTable table = (UIExtendedDataTable)evt.getComponent();
         //now you have the table, you can get what you need from it
           DataComponentState savedState = table.getComponentState(); //this object obtained here you can restore to reset the table to it's condition when you obtained the state.
           //or go into the table's hierarchy to retrieve specific values
           Iterator<UIComponent> cols = table.columns();
           while(cols.hasNext()){
           UIColumn col = (UIColumn)cols.next();
             col.getFilterValue(); //Retrieve the current filter value on the column
           }       
    }
   ```
2. Depending on your preference, find a suitable point in the component's lifecycle to restore the values. I'll recommend `preRenderComponent`.

   ```
       public void restoreTableConditions(ComponentSystemEvent evt){
        table.restoreState(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),savedState); //restore the DataComponentState from wherever you stashed it
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It's seems quite nice. At the moment I'm working on solution about which I mentioned before before (one session bean for s&f), so if I'm not succeed I'll try your way and report about the progress.
But still, thank you once again. I've been searching for a solution like that for some time, but without effects.